# unix command for a specific scenario

Tags: unix

How to update the 3rd and 4th column values based on 1st column value.

Input File:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4 
Mukesh|kumar|abhishek|kumar 
Akshay|rana|mmm|
Akshay|||
```

```sh
awk -F'|' '{OFS="|"} {if($1=="Akshay")sub($3,"UPDATE")sub($4,"UPDATED");}1' tmp.txt
```

Expected output:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4 
Mukesh|kumar|abhishek|kumar 
Akshay|rana|UPDATE|UPDATED 
Akshay||UPDATE|UPDATED
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"            # set both field delimiters at once
} 
{
    if($1=="Akshay") {    # if, then:
        $3="UPDATE"       # just set the variable, no need for sub()
        $4="UPDATED"
    }
}1
' file
```

Output:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4
Mukesh|kumar|abhishek|kumar
Akshay|rana|UPDATE|UPDATED
Akshay||UPDATE|UPDATED
```

One-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {if($1=="Akshay"){$3="UPDATE";$4="UPDATED"}}1' file
```